# With Typo3, is it possible to have some kind of data store?

Tags: variables, global-variables, environment-variables, typo3, datastore

I've worked with Typo3 for a few years, but I mostly used it as a CMS. Now I have a specific need and can't figure out if I need to find an extension, write TypoScript or if this need can be filled with an existing Typo3 feature.

The documentation being what it is, here I am.

The need I have is similar to needing a taxe rates table (it's not my case so don't point me to some taxe rates management extension).

I need to have variables set in some data store and display this data on the frontend in function of the date.
For example :

```
Effective date             Rate

2010-10-01                 10,00$
2011-10-01                 10,50$
2012-10-01                 11,00$
```

Basically, I need a non technical user to be able to edit this data store and I need to be able to use this rate on the frontend as a variable.

I'm pretty sure someone has one something similar in the past. I'm just a bit lost with Typo3.

Anyone knows the **best** way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a rought guess:

You could create a new Extension "yourextension" with an table "tx_yourextension_rate" with the kickstarter. Add the fields "effective date" and "rate" including start/stop times. Install the plugin - you will only need the table, no plugin!

Create a folder where your users stores the records.

```
lib.rate = CONTENT
lib.rate {
  select {
    # create a folder, where your users stores the records:
    pidInList = 100 
    # just one record
    max = 1
    orderBy = effective_date ASC
  }
  table = tx_yourextension_rate
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
     field = rate
     wrap = actual rate: <span class="rate">|</span>
  }
}
```

Use lib.rate where you need.

Comment: Okay, looks good. If my understanding of TypoScript is correct a user will then me able to use a wildcard like this --> ###THE_RATE###. And I'll be able to replace that wildcard with my rate value by doing this --> marks.MY_RATE = lib.rate ?

I'll try it. If this works, sir, you've made my day.

Comment: oh, no i meant you create a new plugin (aka extension). This extension provides an new table with only the fields you need. Your user will edit that records with built in start/stop fields etc. Just start an extension via kickstarter - add an new table with fields you need.

Comment: Okay, so creating an extension with kickstarter helped me immensely, but I'm stuck at the 95% bar. You seem to know your way through Typo3 so this is going to seem dumb. This doesn't work : `page.stdWrap.parseFunc.short { MY_RATE = lib.rate }`. MY_RATE is raplced by 'lib.rate'. Of course I want MY_RATE to be replaced with the **content** of `lib.rate`. How to I get there. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, short does only an str_replace. But you could use stdWrap.replacement (since TYPO3 4.6) http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/5/#id553430